# .htaccess URL redirected, clean url, trailing slash, force www

Tags: .htaccess, web, clean-urls, trailing-slash

So I redirected one of my domains (which we'll call domain.com) into one of my subdirectories (which we'll call file) and I'm trying to achieve links that will cut down the index?page=, force the www, and have trailing slashes available for all pages.

Currently I have

domain.com/index?page=about or domain.com/splash

where I'd like www.domain.com/about/ or www.domain.com/splash/

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) file/$1 [NC,L,NS]

ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/splash
```

I'm not well versed with Apache if you can't tell, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond   %{HTTP:Host}        !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$              http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   ^([\w\-]+)$         /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$              /index.php?page=$1       [L]

ErrorDocument 404                 /splash/
```

Be careful to use `302` (temporary) redirections instead of `301` (permanent) ones during your debugging phase, as your browser would "remember" the permanent redirections and not take into account the new configuration of your website.